# zsh:1: command not found: python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am new to using Jupyter and i have been using kaggle and google colab for data science but colab has gpu limitations which is why i switched to jupyter

i have installed python long ago so all i did was check for pip upgrade and then performed following commands:

```
pip3 install jupyter 
jupyter notebook (to open jupyter)
```

i was able to open jupyter and was executning the cell blocks until i came to this code cell

```
!python -m spacy init fill-config /Users/atharvasankhe/Files/resumeparse/data/training/base_config.cfg config.cfg
```

and i got this error

```
zsh:1: command not found: python
```

what i understand from this is error is that python cant be found but i use python regularly on different IDE
Also when i run !python i can see the python version

I tried using jupyterlab
but it was no different result that what i was facing already

Comment: its just the python command that cannot be found, maybe it is not in your PATH, or it has another name like pytohn3? But generally this is impossible to answer without details.

Comment: what details do you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have v3.X of python installed? If so you need to run

```
!python3 -m spacy init fill-config /Users/atharvasankhe/Files/resumeparse/data/training/base_config.cfg config.cfg
```

(note the python3, not python).

Since this question is tagged as python 3.x, this should solve your problem.

Comment: ohhhh ig its python3 yea ok ill try it out

Comment: yep you were right it was a dumb mistake in retrospect
also it expplains why it worked on kaggle and colab but not on my machine because my machine has python3
would have given you upvote but my reputation is less than 15